# Passing Click Events To Controls In Draggable Div

Tags: html, controls, draggable, onmouseclick

We have a web application using ASP, VB and Javascript.  In it, we have a table of items allowing comments on the items.  The comment code is implemented using a div containing some controls - a couple of text boxes and some buttons.

I've recently added basic draggability to the div using Mike Hall's generic drag script from http://www.brainjar.com.  The intention is to be able to move the comment div out of the way of the other text on the page.

The problem is that the text boxes now fail to capture their click events.  No commenting is possible.  The two buttons on the div seem to work OK.

I've been trawling through the Internet for a while now and have tried many possible solutions, including hard-coding the z-order, all to no apparent effect.

Here's the code behind the div:

```
<script src="Scripts/GenericDrag.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<div id="divComment" style="DISPLAY: none; LEFT: 800px; WIDTH: 340px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 800px; HEIGHT: 140px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: teal; BORDER: 1px; PADDING: 10px"
onmousedown="dragStart(event)" runat="server">
    <TABLE>
        <tr>
            <td>Kaizen&nbsp;ID</td>
            <td><asp:textbox id="txtCommentID" runat="server" Width="132px"></asp:textbox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Comment</td>
            <td><asp:textbox id="txtComment" runat="server" Width="250" Height="72px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:textbox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:button id="btnComment" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text="Comment"></asp:button></td>
            <td align="right"><input onclick="divComment.style.display='none'" type="button" value="Cancel"></td>
        </tr>
    </TABLE>
</div>
```

btnComment has an onClick function, but it only does something noticeable if the comment string in the text box is non-empty.

If I remove the inclusion of GenericDrag.js, the draggability stops but people can enter comments again.

I've tried this with the latest FF, IE and Chrome on both Win XP and Win7.  All behave identically in this regard.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.  I would not be at all surprised to find I've done something basic incorrectly.

Geoff

Comment: I should add that there's a second div using similar code, but containing a drop-down and a text box.  The drop-down list also does not allow user entry if the draggability is enabled.

Comment: I tried using the "draggable" property, but it did not seem to make the div moveable.  Now that it has a border, I'll try again.